# Git - the remote end hung up unexpectedly

Tags: git

I have to install an application on a CentOS server via SSH.
If I launch the makefile at the command `git clone  -v git://github.com/AKSW/RDFauthor.git libraries/RDFauthor` the compilation stops with this error:

> fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 3):

That is using the git protocol (port 9418), which maybe blocked. Try using the https ( https://github.com/AKSW/RDFauthor.git ) url in the makefile.

Comment: Yes, now it works but at the end i have that warning: make: warning:  Clock skew detected.  Your build may be incomplete.

Comment: @frakorn - That is something in your makefile and nothing to do with git / this question.

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same error message when i've made the following commands from Github help:

```
$ git remote add upstream git://github.com/octocat/Spoon-Knife.git
$ git fetch upstream
```

The error was corrected when i inserted the remote repository using the following syntax:

```
$ git remote add upstream git@github.com:octocat/Spoon-Knife.git
```