# git 800MB evernote backup - remote end hung up unexpectedly error

Tags: git, push

I seem to be experiencing the "remote end hung up unexpectedly error" documented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9446632/git-the-remote-end-hung-up-unexpectedly), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26136103/git-push-fails-remote-end-hung-up-unexpectedly)

In my case though, I'm trying to push an initial copy of my Evernote back up (about 800MB compressed). On a 80KB/s upload link, it takes about 3 hours.

I've experienced the same error on both [Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/) and [GitLab](https://about.gitlab.com/).  I'm using the free version for both services. Both services claim to support this sort of repo size

Any idea what could be causing the issue? Error message is below.

Thanks!

p.s. only thing that I configured is to leave CRLF setting as is (disabling git's autocorrect)

```
Counting objects: 13821, done. Delta compression using up to 8
threads. Compressing objects: 100% (13608/13608), done. Write failed:
Broken pipe62/13821), 44.26 MiB | 114.00 KiB/s fatal: The remote end
hung up unexpectedly error: pack-objects died of signal 13 error:
failed to push some refs to
'git@bitbucket.org:<username>/<repo>.git'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While a repo limit is usually 1GB (on GitHub or Bitbucket), one *file* cannot exceed a certain size.

For instance, it is [100MB on GitHub](https://help.github.com/articles/what-is-my-disk-quota/).
If the backup has a file (like an archive) greater than 100MB, the all push will be rejected.

GitHub has [support for larger files with LFS](https://help.github.com/articles/versioning-large-files/) (early acces), GitLab is [planning to support it also](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/1404) (update Nov. 2015: **[GitLab does support LFS](https://about.gitlab.com/2015/11/23/announcing-git-lfs-support-in-gitlab/)**), and has support for git-annex.

Comment: That was exactly it @VonC. It pushed fine after I removed the 100MB Note from Evernote. Spent 5 days back and forth with bitbucket support and got no where. Thanks to your answer it works now. Much obliged!

Answer (score 1):

Based on the previous answer and my personal experience, GIT should definitely not be used as a storage place for large files (resources), but rather for small files (code files). The reasoning behind this is keeping a change history of the files uploaded into the repository (so it is easily possible to roll back to previous versions of the same file).

An 800MB backup file should be stored on a repository such as Dropbox, which is oriented towards resource storage, and not code storage.